# Slightly more complicated Spark word count

Tags: apache-spark

I have a large list of file locations. I want to read parquet from those locations, group by some column, do a count, and reduce by key.

```
var commaDelim = spark.sparkContext.textFile("s3://some_location")
var locs = commDelim.flatmap(l => l.split(","))
locs.map(loc => spark.read.parquet(loc).groupBy("col").count ...
```

Not sure how to turn the count dataframe into a format that can be reduced by key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass list files directly to `parquet` function like below

```
val locs = [file1,file2,file3,...]
```

```
spark.read.parquet(locs:_*)
.select("col")
.as[String]
.flatMap(value => value.split("\\s+"))
.groupBy($"value")
.agg(count("*").as("count"))
.show(false)
```

Comment: I tried this, but the list of files is too large for the driver...

Comment: whatever you are passing list of files are loaded and processed on cluster not on driver node.